# paste text in text field onclick

Tags: android, webview

i have two activities. **MainActivity** for getting page URL and the **Download** Activity for letting the user paste the page url manually in the form. this works fine. However, i would like to automate the process.

this is how i copy the page URL(**in MainActivity**)-

```
public void grabvideo(View view) {
    String url = webView.getUrl();
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setText(url);
    } else {
        android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData
                .newPlainText("text label", url);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    }
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "✂" + url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Download.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and this is how i paste the text in the field programmatically (hardcoded text)-

```
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection lost",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('mediaurl').value='some value';})()");
    }
```

now how do i paste the copied text programmatically? instead of pasting the hard coded text

Comment: I dont know if it'll work or not, but try once `document.getElementById('mediaurl').value='"+copiedText+"';`

Comment: i created the field "copiedText" and it is pasting "null" in the field

Comment: where you're getting the copied text?? Show your code.

Comment: dude, the first part of the code is used to get the copied text

Comment: Can you pass the copied text in the `Intent`? Use `intent.putExtra("url", url);` and get that in your other activity like `getIntent().getStringExtra("url");`

Comment: i have fixed it already using shared preference